# php plugin or library to let users set cron?

Tags: content-management-system, cron

i am making a CMS,

I need a premade solution that lets users set time for CRON ?

it'd be nice if stuff like ajax calendar was also included.

Comment: If you are creating a product to ship, this is hardly going to work because in 99.999% of environments the user PHP runs under is not allowed to access the crontab.

Comment: well a script needs to run every specified interval by the user....how can i do this ?

Comment: If you don't have access to cron, you can just update a timer on each request, and if the timer should run, run it, but this is ugly and should only be used for some cleanup job.

The typical solution is to document this need, and let the user decide what to do. Provide xxx.php to be run every X seconds, and let the sysadmin deal with it.

Comment: is there simple calendar/time plugin , where users can specify the intervals? i would store this data then into dB, and then set up crontab on the server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice tutorial of how to make such thing: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Also, you can try this:
http://greenservr.com/projects/crontab/crontab.phps
This worked for me because the rule for crontab at my hosting provider is that every 30 seconds some script looks for a file with rules for crontab in the main directory. It reads it and launches the jobs if necessary.